# button setEnable method in android

Tags: java, android

I have 3 disabled buttons.

I try to enable those 3 buttons using the following code

```
...
button1.setEnabled(true);
button2.setEnabled(true);
button3.setEnabled(true);
...
```

However, only the first button will be enabled.

It looks like the setEnabled method block the UI thread or something like that.

What am I doing wrong here ?

I can change the order of the statement for example :

```
...
button2.setEnabled(true);
button3.setEnabled(true);
button1.setEnabled(true);
...
```

But then only button2 will be enable....

Comment: Do you have the onClick set?

Comment: yes I do have the onClick set

Comment: could you post more of your code?

Comment: post ur whole code with xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution :

create an handler for the UI :

```
myHandler = new Handler()
{
     @OVerride
     public void handleMessage(Message msg)
     {
           if(((String)msg.obj).equals("enablebutton"))
           {
                //set all button enable here
           }
     }
}

...

Message msg = new Message();
msg.obj = "enablebutton";
GameHandler.this.myHandler.sendMessage(msg);     

...
```